# Sequelize trying to query a dropped column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've dropped a column from a model in my database using a sequelize migration and, even though the migration executes with success, sequelize is still trying to query the same field in my Node.js application.

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
db.Alarm.all({ logging: console.log })
.catch(console.log)
```

Here's part of the query log output (**user_id** is the dropped column):

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "driver_id", "dismissed_by", (...), "user_id"
FROM "alarms" AS "Alarm" WHERE "Alarm"."deleted_at" IS NULL;
```

And here's part of the *catch* output:

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: column "user_id" does not exist]
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
message: 'column "user_id" does not exist',
original:
 { [error: column "user_id" does not exist]
 name: 'error',
 length: 101,
 severity: 'ERROR',
 code: '42703',
 detail: undefined,
 hint: undefined,
 position: '257',
 internalPosition: undefined,
 internalQuery: undefined,
 where: undefined,
 schema: undefined,
 table: undefined,
 column: undefined,
 dataType: undefined,
 constraint: undefined,
 file: 'parse_relation.c',
 line: '3090',
 routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
 sql: 'SELECT "id", "driver_id", "dismissed_by", (...), "user_id" FROM "alarms" AS "Alarm" WHERE "Alarm"."deleted_at" IS NULL;' }
```

I've removed the *user_id* field and the *belongsTo(User)* association from my Alarm model. The only reference my model has to User is by the column *dismissed_by*, with can be seen in the outputs above. I've also checked my Alarms table in PostgreSQL and indeed there's no *user_id* column, so I've no idea of what's going on.

**Update**: This problem seems to be affecting only foreign keys columns. I've been able to add/remove/rename other columns from the model successfully but got the same problem when renaming the column *dismissed_by*.

Comment: perhaps having the models before and after the migration could work. Need more info to help

Comment: @DanRocha the problem was an association I've forgot to remove in one of the models

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I've missed a hasMany association in the User model (for the user_id column). It just worked fine when I removed it =]